# improve spring batch job performance

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-batch

I am in the process of implementing a spring batch job for our file upload process. My requirement is to read a flat file, apply business logic then store it in DB then post a Kafka message.

I have a single chunk-based step that uses a custom reader, processor, writer. The process works fine but takes a lot of time to process a big file.

It takes 15 mins to process a file having 60K records. I need to reduce it to less than 5 mins, as we will be consuming much bigger files than this.

As per  https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html I understand making it multithreaded would give a performance boost, at the cost of restart ability. However, I am using FlatFileItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter and none of them is thread-safe.

Any suggestions as to how to improve performance here?

Here is the writer code:-

```
 public void write(List<? extends Message> items) {
        items.forEach(this::process);
    }
    
  private void process(Message message) {
        if (message == null)
            return;
        try {
           //message is a DTO that have info about success or failure.
            if (success) {
                //post kafka message using spring cloud stream
                //insert record in DB using spring jpaRepository
            } else {
                 //insert record in DB using spring jpaRepository
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           //throw exception
        }
    }
```

Best regards,
Preeti

Comment: Before going to multi-threading or partitioning, have you profiled your current job? What is the value of the chunk size? Low values mean a lot of transactions which could be a performance issue. What is the bottle neck of your job? Is it you processing logic or the IO (read/write operations)? Those questions are really important to see if you really need to scale your job, and if yes, which scaling strategy to implement.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for getting back. I have defined chunk size as 500. I did try to log time metrics around reader, writer, processor. Writer was the one taking most of the time. Here are the micrometer stats generated by spring batch:-Writer (spring.batch.chunk.write)
statistic: "TOTAL_TIME",
value: 766.972706343

Process (spring.batch.item.process)
statistic: "TOTAL_TIME",
value: 3.238209216

Read (spring.batch.item.read)
statistic: "TOTAL_TIME",
value: 4.164657738

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Can you share your writer config? Also, which job repository do you use? The default Map-based job repository is probably slowing things down.

Comment: Thank you. I am using default MapJobRegistry. Writer implements ItemWriter<?> . Updated my original post with writer's logic.

Comment: The map based job repository can be slow and is deprecated: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3780,I recommend using the JDBC based job repository. Moreover, your writer does not seem to use bulk updates: you are issuing a save operation for each item in a loop. You should do something like `saveAll(items)` to save all items at once in a single bulk operation. We introduced similar improvements in 4.3: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#performanceImprovements which you can use for inspiration.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I am using JBDC based job repository. However I understand what you are saying, but my requirement is to save each element individually after posting to kafka.

Comment: In this case, if you hit the limits and you think your job cannot be optimized further, then you can try a multi-threaded step or a locally partitioned step (ie a thread per worker step). In both cases, you need to make sure your batch artifacts (reader, processor, writer) are thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Wanted to pick your brain on another approach I was thinking I noticed if I use CompositeItemWriter i.e.use JpaItemWriter to perform DB commits, and separate writer that post messages to kafka in @Async call. This did help expediting process. However I am not able to envision behavior:-
1. When something goes wrong while posting message to kafka and execution stops. Would it rollback DB inserts?
2. What are the repercussions on restart-ability
I understand with Multithreading I would loose restart behavior and partitioning will complicate my flow further.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below SO thread and refer the git hub source code for parallel processing

[Spring Batch multiple process for heavy load with multiple thread under every process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029567/spring-batch-multiple-process-for-heavy-load-with-multiple-thread-under-every-pr/66088652#66088652)

[Spring batch to process huge data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150694/spring-batch-to-process-huge-data/66153473#66153473)

Comment: Thanks. Will check.